# Confusion about unpacking lists in R

Tags: r

I'm befuddled by how R is dealing with lists and data frames.  For example:

```
agg = function() {
  df1 = data.frame(a=1:5,b=1:5)
  df2 = data.frame(a=11:15,b=11:15)  
  return(list(df1, df2))
}
res = agg()

# returns NULL
res[1]$a

# returns 1:5
res[[1]]$a
```

I don't understand why the first element of res is not a data frame; rather, I need double-referencing to get at the elements.  I read Hadley Wickham's excellent Data Structures chapter in his Advanced R website, but still can't figure out what's up with this example.  Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: You might be confused about what `[[` means. You aren't nesting `[`s so it's probably not accurate to call it "double referencing." `[[` is its own operator (actually a function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single square brackets `[]` are used to index *vectors* in R.  Double square brackets `[[]]` are used to index *lists*. You have a list, so `[]` doesn't work:

```
is.list(res)
# [1] TRUE
str(res)
# List of 2
# $ :'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ a: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  ..$ b: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
# $ :'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ a: int [1:5] 11 12 13 14 15
#  ..$ b: int [1:5] 11 12 13 14 15
```

See [?[](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html), [vectors](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Vectors-and-assignment), and [lists](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Lists) for more information.  The following SO posts might also help:

- [What are the differences between R vector and R list data types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8594814/1217536)
- [Learning R for someone used to MATLAB, and confusion with R data types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15316581/1217536)
- [how to understand list(list(object)) in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20296379/1217536)

Comment: A good reference is R inferno sec: 8.1.54 `list subscripting`

Answer (score 1):

First element of the list is a list, thus `agg[1]` returns a list. 
You are looking for the first component of the list, which is saved in `agg[[1]]`. Thus `agg[[1]]$a` works.

E.g., take a look at the following

```
res[[1]]$a

res[1][[1]]$a

res[1][1][[1]]$a

res[1][1][1][[1]]$a
```

They are all returning the column `a` of the first component of the list. In these cases, they are all the same list, i.e. the first element of `res`.

Hope that makes sense.